# PostgreSql - calling stored proc to bulk upsert (insert on conflict) data isn't working via npgsql

Tags: postgresql, npgsql, upsert

I am trying bulk upsert data to via a stored proc. Following a few threads, I ended up creating a stored procs passing input records as json and using json_populate_recorset internally like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.test_proc3(IN par_records character varying)
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    insert into firsttable
    select * from json_populate_recordset(NULL::uttfirsttable, (par_records)::json)
    on conflict(id)
    do update set
        createddate = excluded.createddate,
        name = excluded.name;
END;
$BODY$;
```

btw uttfirsttable is a type declared as

```
CREATE TYPE public.uttfirsttable AS
(
    id integer,
    name character varying(100),
    createddate timestamp without time zone
);
```

This works fine if I call it directly from PgAdmin as

```
call test_proc3(
    '[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "newfirst",
    "createddate": "2021-03-10T10:03:19.3589317+11:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "sixth",
    "createddate": "2021-03-10T10:03:19.3689052+11:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "newsecond",
    "createddate": "2021-03-10T10:03:19.3689052+11:00"
  }
]'
);
```

However my .net code is somehow failing to insert/update anything despite passing exactly same json to the stored proc

```
string recordsJson = "[{\"id\": 1,\"name\": \"newfirst\",\"createddate\": \"2021-03-10T10:03:19.3589317+11:00\"},{\"id\": 6,\"name\": \"sixth\",\"createddate\": \"2021-03-10T10:03:19.3689052+11:00\"},{\"id\": 2,\"name\": \"newsecond\",\"createddate\": \"2021-03-10T10:03:19.3689052+11:00\"}]";// JsonConvert.SerializeObject(records, Formatting.Indented);

                using (var lConn = GetConnection())
                {
                    using (var trans = lConn.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        using (var cmd = GetCommand("call test_proc3(@par_records)", lConn, trans, System.Data.CommandType.Text))
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@par_records", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, recordsJson.Length).Value = recordsJson;

                            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

result has -1 value in it. Just for testing if I replace the 'call test_proc3(@par_records) with the full query from the stored proc, then cmd.ExecuteNonQuery returns 3, however still no records are added/updated.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Took me hours to notice a careless mistake of missing
`trans.Commit`
before exiting the function.